# Database view missing from IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I can`t see the "database" view in "View -> Tool windows" in Intellij 12.

Anyone experienced the same problem? How do I get it back?

Comment: Do you have the community or the ultimate version?

Comment: Do you have "Database Support" plugin enabled?

Comment: And look around the 3 borders of your screen (left, bottom, right), perhaps you moved it :) Also, were there any errors in the error log? this would tell you if it failed to start up.

Comment: Okey, saw some problems in the log that the heroku intellij-plugin was causing problems. Removed the plugin and restarted, and the database plugin plus a couple of other ones showed up! So moral is: if any plugins are causing problems, uninstall them, cause they may brake others! :-)

Comment: Is the Database View window only available in the ultimate version?

Comment: @JWoodchuck Yes.

Answer (score 35):

This can be a repeat of deep's answer. But will help newbies who aren't familiar with Intellij jargon's.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> will take you to settings. From Settings go to plugins.

Add Database Navigator from the repository if it is not enabled.

[image]

After this go to View-> Tool Windows -> Database navigator

[image]

Answer (score 21):

As of intellij version 2017.1, search for the plugin "Database navigator" in Settings -> Plugins. Then you can open the db browser from View -> Tool Windows -> DB Browser.

Comment: It should be noted, I believe that the Database Navigator is a 3rd party plugin, and NOT the official Database View developed by Jetbrains

Answer (score 15):

Btw. you most likely don't have the Database option under View -> Tool Windows if you're running IntelliJ Community.

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer.  If it doesn't show up, it's because you're using a version that doesn't come with the official database view developed by Jetbrains. You can find 3rd party addons, such as the other answers suggest, but they are 3rd party and not official.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. Even searching for the plugin "Database navigator" didn't work for me. So first I had to install database navigator from repositories and install it first. (*File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Browse Repositories* | Search for 'Database Navigator' and install it. Sometime it will require a restart after the installation.)

Additional :

This would install Database navigator. But it's not possible to create tables from database navigator. It will give this message.

[image: SQLite support error]

In order to create a table, you have to install sqlite3 command line tool from official SQLite official site. Then you can use terminal to create tables and other operations.

`SQLiteStudio` is much easier option. Hope this would helpsomeone.

Answer (score 1):

Database tools are supported in the Ultimate edition only: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Answer (score 1):

Database tools are built-in with intellij new versions. You can
Go to **Plugins** in the installed section, search for **Database Tools and SQL** mark it check, **Apply** and restart your idea. You will see the Database tool in your sidebar

Answer (score 0):

in the IDE menu bar, select the menu view> tool windows, if "Database Tools and SQL" plugin is enabled, we'll find a menu "database", so click on it to open the correspending panel

Comment: hi, is the plugin name "Database support" exactly? Because I can't find anything under this name. You can try here: https://plugins.jetbrains.com
Is this Ultimate edition only?

Comment: The plugin is named Database Tools and SQL (see Settings>plugins)

Comment: `Settings` > `Plugins` > `Browse Repositories` then search for "Database Navigator" by a provider called "DATABASE". This adds a new option to `View` > `Tool Windows` called "DB Browser"

Answer (score -1):

I am just copy and pasting answer of jorgen.ringen (who asked the question) from the comment.

Okey, saw some problems in the log that the heroku intellij-plugin was causing problems. Removed the plugin and restarted, and the database plugin plus a couple of other ones showed up!

> So moral is: if any plugins are causing problems, uninstall them,
>   cause they may break others! :-)